# Display query string in specific format in mvc form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

when we submit form with get method, it pass parameters as querystring like below:
http://localhost:2564/Blog?SearchManufacturer=land

But, I want to display query string like below:

http://localhost:2564/Blog/SearchManufacturer/land

I have tried below code. but still it passing with query string.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Blog", new { CurrentFilter = Model.SearchManufacturer }, FormMethod.Get))
  {
     <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
       <label>Search Manufacturer</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchManufacturer, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>                                                
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
</div>
}
```

also, in route.config, I have used different combinations of routing as below.

```
  routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Blog/SearchManufacturer/{SearchManufacturer}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });            
            routes.MapRoute("BlogbyPageSortandFilter", "Blog/Page/{page}/CurrentFilter/{currentFilter}/SortBy/{sort}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogbyPageandSort", "Blog/Page/{page}/SortBy/{sort}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogbyPageandFilter", "Blog/Page/{page}/CurrentFilter/{currentFilter}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogbySortandFilter", "Blog/SortBy/{sort}/CurrentFilter/{currentFilter}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("SortBlog", "Blog/SortBy/{sort}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogbyPage", "Blog/Page/{page}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("BlogbyFilter", "Blog/CurrentFilter/{currentFilter}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
```

these routing are used for sorting, paging, filtering using Pagedlist.mvc. all these are working fine. but searching is not passing parameter as in routing. it is passing parameter as query string.

please help me to fix this.

Thanks

Lalitha

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your form method is set to GET type, when you submit the form, form data will be appended to the action attribute url as querystring values (which starts with `?`). This is something the browsers does. Your asp.net mvc routing cannot do anything on this.

If you absolutely need the `/Blog/SearchManufacturer/land` url when the form is submitted, you can hijack the form submit event with client side javascript and update the url however you want. The below code will give you the output you want.

```
$(function () {

    $("#searchFrm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formAction = $(this).attr("action");
        if (!formAction.endsWith('/')) {
            formAction += '/';
        }
        var url = formAction +'SearchManufacturer/'+ $("#SearchManufacturer").val();
        window.location.href = url;
    });

});
```

Assuming your form tag has an Id value "searchFrm"

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Blog",FormMethod.Get,new { id="searchFrm"}))
{
  // Your existing code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hi Shyju, Thanks for the answer. Nice explanation. It is working perfectly.